# How to specify child objects type in an NSArray with Mantle

Tags: ios, frameworks, github-mantle

If I have a dictionary like

```
{
  name: "Bob",
  cars: [
    { make: "ford", year: "1972" },
    { make: "mazda", year: "2000" }
  ],
}
```

and two models like:

```
@interface CarModel : MTLModel

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *make;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *year;

@end

@interface PersonModel : MTLModel

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *cars;

@end
```

How do I use Mantle so that my array of cars in my person model are CarModels?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ah figured it out.  I needed to add a private method:

```
+ (NSValueTransformer *)carsTransformer
{
    return [NSValueTransformer mtl_externalRepresentationArrayTransformerWithModelClass:[CarModel class]];
}
```

and make sure I used:

```
[PersonModel modelWithExternalRepresentation:dict];
```

Comment: This method is deprecated, the new one is: [NSValueTransformer mtl_JSONArrayTransformerWithModelClass:[CarModel class]];

Comment: It didn't seem to drop into the property transformer method until I parsed the JSON like this:

MyModelClass * myModel = [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[MyModelClass class] fromJSONDictionary:jsonDictionary error:&error];

Comment: Don't forget `#import <Mantle/NSValueTransformer+MTLPredefinedTransformerAdditions.h>`

Comment: now you have to use [MTLJSONAdapter arrayTransformerWithModelClass:[CarModel class]];

Answer (score 13):

`+[NSValueTransformer mtl_externalRepresentationArrayTransformerWithModelClass:]` is deprecated. The new API is `+[NSValueTransformer mtl_JSONArrayTransformerWithModelClass:]`.

After switching to the new API, the models can be initialized with the default initializers provided by, e.g., `MTLJSONAdapter`.

Comment: Both of these are now deprecated, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/30735107/1652402

Answer (score 12):

A note on:

```
[NSValueTransformer mtl_JSONArrayTransformerWithModelClass:CarModel.class];
```

This methods seems to now be deprecated. I'm using this new method in my code and it appears to be working just fine:

```
[MTLJSONAdapter arrayTransformerWithModelClass:CarModel.class];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
+ (NSValueTransformer *)carsJSONTransformer {
    return [NSValueTransformer mtl_JSONArrayTransformerWithModelClass:CarModel.class];
}
```

Read more [here](http://www.objc.at/mantle)

Comment: This one works fine for me, and is simple and clear.

Comment: @GoldThumb actually, Mantle grows over time, some of its API change, so we need to track that change if we plan to update Mantle

Answer (score 0):

```
+[NSValueTransformer mtl_JSONArrayTransformerWithModelClass:]
```

This method is deprecated. New method is:

```
  + (NSValueTransformer *)carsTransformer
    {
        return [MTLJSONAdapter arrayTransformerWithModelClass:[CarsModel class]];
    }
```