# MTLModels within MTLModels?

Tags: ios, github-mantle

I have a web service that returns a JSON of an object, and within that object there is a list of other objects. How can I get Mantle to create an object for each one of these nested objects, rather than giving me a dictionary for each one of them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to specify child objects type in an NSArray with Mantle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883693/how-to-specify-child-objects-type-in-an-nsarray-with-mantle)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be done using `mtl_JSONDictionaryTransformerWithModelClass:` tranformer introduced by Mantle some time ago.

Let's look at the example taken from [Mantle project readme](https://github.com/github/Mantle/blob/master/README.md) itself:

```
@interface GHIssue : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) GHUser *assignee;

@end
```

```
@implementation GHIssue

+ (NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey {
    return @{
        @"assignee": @"assignee",
    };
}

+ (NSValueTransformer *)assigneeJSONTransformer {
    return [NSValueTransformer mtl_JSONDictionaryTransformerWithModelClass:[GHUser class]];
}

@end
```

Assuming `GHUser` is a subclass of `MTLModel` conforming to `MTLJSONSerializing` protocol, everything should work perfectly.

UPDATE: The above solution is now deprecated. The correct method to use now would be

```
return [MTLJSONAdapter dictionaryTransformerWithModelClass:GHUser.class];
```

inside the 'assigneeJSONTransformer' method.

Comment: This fails if assignee field is empty/null. How can I check that and skip transformation in this case?